# Java,Add user into Active Directory (samba-ad)

Tags: javascript, java, swing

I try to add users in my active directory (samba-ad). The addition goes well except that the name of the user appears in a character string for example yanick gives $BE23343... in the active directory

indeed I retrieve the information that the user would have typed through the graphical interface and I add in the context

here is what i tried

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class ADManagerUI extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField cnField;
  private JTextField snField;
  private JTextField uidField;
  private JTextField passwordField;
  private JTextField mailField;
  private JTextField displayNameField;
  private JTextField descriptionField;
  private JButton addButton;
  private JButton deleteButton;
  private JButton modifyButton;
  

  public ADManagerUI() {
    // Initialisation de la fenêtre
    setTitle("Gestionnaire d'utilisateurs AD");
    setSize(600, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Création des champs de texte et des labels
    JLabel cnLabel = new JLabel("Nom complet :");
    cnField = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel snLabel = new JLabel("Nom de famille :");
    snField = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel uidLabel = new JLabel("Nom d'utilisateur :");
    uidField = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Mot de passe :");
    passwordField = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel mailLabel = new JLabel("Adresse e-mail :");
    mailField = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel displayNameLabel = new JLabel("Nom affiché :");
    displayNameField = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel("Description :");
    descriptionField = new JTextField(20);

    // Création des boutons
    addButton = new JButton("Ajouter un utilisateur");
    deleteButton = new JButton("Supprimer un utilisateur");
    modifyButton = new JButton("Modifier un utilisateur");

    // Ajout des champs de texte et des labels à la fenêtre
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    add(cnLabel, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(cnField, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    add(snLabel, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(snField, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    add(uidLabel, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(uidField, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    add(passwordLabel, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(passwordField, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    add(mailLabel, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add( mailField, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    add(displayNameLabel, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(displayNameField, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    add(descriptionLabel , constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(descriptionField, constraints);
    // Ajout des boutons à la fenêtre
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 8;
    add(addButton, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    add(deleteButton, constraints);
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    add(modifyButton, constraints);
    // Ajout des listeners aux boutons
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new DeleteButtonListener());
    modifyButton.addActionListener(new ModifyButtonListener());
}

// Classe interne pour gérer le clic sur le bouton "Ajouter"
class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Les informations de connexion au serveur LDAP
    String ldapAdServer = "ldap://serveur.domaine.com";
    String ldapUsername = "cn=admin,dc=domaine,dc=com";
    String ldapPassword = "mot_de_passe";

    // Les informations du nouvel utilisateur
    String cn = cnField.getText();
    String sn = snField.getText();
    String uid = uidField.getText();
    String password = passwordField.getText();
    String mail = mailField.getText();
    String displayName = displayNameField.getText();
    String description = descriptionField.getText();

    // Connexion au serveur LDAP
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);

    try {
      // Création du contexte LDAP
      DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

      // Création de l'entrée pour le nouvel utilisateur
      Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes();
      Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
      objClasses.add("top");
      objClasses.add("person");
      objClasses.add("organizationalPerson");
      objClasses.add("user");
      attrs.put(objClasses);
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("cn", cn));
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("sn", sn));
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("uid", uid));
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("userPassword", password));
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("mail", mail));
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("displayName", displayName));
      attrs.put(new BasicAttribute("description", description));

      String dn = "cn=" + cn + ",ou=utilisateurs,dc=domaine,dc=com";
      ctx.createSubcontext(dn, attrs);
      ctx.close();

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Utilisateur ajouté avec succès !");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erreur lors de l'ajout de l'utilisateur !");
    }
  }
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ADManagerUI adUI = new ADManagerUI();
  adUI.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: is javascript related?

Comment: [mcve] please ..  mind the M! that is nothing unrelated but still runnable as-is to demonstrate the issue you are describing. That said: in your shoes I would first try to add a user in a plain non-ui context (use hard-coded data) to verify that the issue is related to swing.